# Why can I use comma at the end of the line in the following callback function inside the map function?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, map-function

In javascript, I thought we aren't allowed to end the line with comma if we were inside a closure. Why is the following code snippet an exception?

And why does it not work if I put a comma after `k.c = 'asd'`?

```js
let kk = [
{ a: 'asd', b: 'ddd' }, 
{ a: 'hhh', b: 'dsd' }
];

kk = kk.map(k => {
  k.a = 'new',
    k.b = 'new1',
    k.c = 'asd'
  return k
})

console.log(kk)
```

Comment: You can paste the code here: https://astexplorer.net/ and see how it is parsed :) `k.a = ..., k.b = ..., ...` is a single expression, whereas `return ...` is a statement. If you put a comma after the last assignment, the parser will try to interpret `return ...` as an expression as well, but it isn't one so an error is thrown.

Comment: thank you, I get it know. expressions and statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an expression, with two uses of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
k.a = 'new', k.b = 'new1', k.c = 'asd'
```

(the trailing semi-colon is optional in JavaScript).

This, however, is a *statement*:

```
return k
```

You can't combine an expression and a statement with the comma operator.

NB: this code should use `.forEach` rather than `.map`.  You should only use the latter when you're returning *new* objects, rather than mutating in place.

Comment: ohhh, I didnt know this. Thank you. You learn something new everyday with javascript I guess. Thanks again

Comment: I agree, this was just for test purpose

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function does two things:
Assign values to variables, and return a value.

Each value assignation is an expression, and multiple expressions can be separated by commas. Your multiple expressions as a whole constitute a statement.

The return at the end of the callback constitutes a statement as well.

Here is the thing: you can't separate statements by commas, only expressions!

Traditionally, you would end statements with a semicolon. In this situation, I think this would help you visualize the distinction between your statements:

```js
let kk = [{a: 'asd', b:'ddd'}, {a: 'hhh', b: 'dsd'}];

kk = kk.map(k => {
  k.a = 'new', k.b = 'new1', k.c = 'asd';
  return k;
})

console.log(kk);
```

I hope this helped you understand what is happening!